# WCF Data service, some question

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, wcf

I've two questions on WCF Data service:

-98% of my needs are covered by the WCF Data service, I only need one business methods, is it possible to mix a WCF Data service? Or should I create a second WCF service only for this method?

-Is it possible to host a WCF Data service into an application? I've a server, and I want that this service is accessible only when the server is launched

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add service operations to your WCF Data Service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668788.aspx
They don't have the same power as true WCF Service operations, but they should fullfil most of your needs in this area (note that they can actually return OData feeds/entries for the client consumption).

You can definitely host WCF Data Service in your own application. The overall description is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668805(VS.100).aspx, but there are bunch of samples around the web, just search for "host WCF Data Service".

Comment: Seems to be really good, just one question about Service operation, can these operation return objects which aren't coming from my data service

Comment: I've added an operation. But now: If I do myself the query through a browser, I get correct results. But: I can't see the operation with OData Explorer, and more problematic, if I add a "Service Reference" in visual studio for this WCF Data Service, I just can't find how to call my operation. Any idea?

Comment: The WCF Data Services client library currently doesn't support service operations directly. If you service operation is a GET, you can use DataServiceContext.Execute to invoke it and get the results. If you're using POST you need to use the HTTP stack directly (probably HttpWebRequest).